# scraping data using python and beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, csv, web-scraping, export

I am trying to scrape data from the At The Races website for horse racing results. I want to be able to include the horse name, horse stall, jockey/trainer name, price, age, weight, distance beaten.

I can get all of this with a simple command of:

for i in soup.select('td'):
    print(i.text)

However, I am presented with the data as below, but it also includes comments which I don't need and I really need it in a  format that can be exported to csv.

I have tried to break the scraping down with a line of code as such:

results = soup.find_all('tr', attrs={'class':'data-number'})

But, that just returns zero results.

Included below is a copy of some of the HTML code from the website itself:

```
 <tr class="" data-number="2" data-draw="7" data-horsename="Attain" data-form="116423" data-weightvaluecloth="152997" data-jockeyname="Mr S Walker"><!--
    HorseID: 2706434--><td class="number-draw"><span>1</span></td>
              <td class="distance">
              </td>
              <td class="horse">
                <div><img class="silk" src="http://data.attheraces.com/images/silks/20180602/20180602lin174002.png" alt="Grey, light blue seams, light blue cap (Boadicea Bloodstock)&#xA;      " data-tooltip="Grey, light blue seams, light blue cap (Boadicea Bloodstock)&#xA;      " data-style="white"><h3><span class="cloth-number">2.
            </span><a href="/form/horse/Attain/GB/2706434?raceid=1039123" target="" data-popup="/form-popup/horse/Attain/GB/2706434?raceid=1039123" class="name summary form-link horse-form-link" data-tooltip="Attain historical data/form" data-style="white tooltip-wide" data-touch="false">Attain</a> 
              (7)
            <a class="horse-tracker-link" href="/horsetracker/add/2706434" data-style="white" data-tooltip="Add Attain to your tracked horses" onclick="LoadHorseTrackerDialog(this); return false;" data-horseid="2706434" data-horsename="Attain" data-comment=""><i class="icon-tracker"></i></a></h3>
                  <p class="closeup">mid-division, headway well over 1f out, soon chasing leaders, led inside final furlong, ran on</p>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td class="starting-price"><span title="op 10/3">5/2 Fav</span></td>
              <td class="age-weight"><span class="age">9</span> <span class="weight">10-12</span> <span class="headgear"></span></td>
              <td class="official-rating"><span class="icon-text-steel or" data-tooltip="&#xA;          <strong>Official Rating: 67</strong>&#xA;        " data-style="white">67</span></td>
              <td class="jockey-trainer"><a href="&#xA;      /form/jockey/Mr-S-Walker/1001848?formtype=jockey&amp;raceid=1039123" data-popup="&#xA;      /form-popup/jockey/Mr-S-Walker/1001848?formtype=jockey&amp;raceid=1039123" class="jockey form-link"><span data-tooltip="Click to view more form for Mr S Walker" data-style="white">Mr S 
Walker</span></a><a href="/form/trainer/Archie-Watson/1479716?formtype=trainer&amp;raceid=1039123" target="" data-popup="/form-popup/trainer/Archie-Watson/1479716?formtype=trainer&amp;raceid=1039123" class="trainer form-link"><span data-tooltip="Click to view more form for Archie Watson" data-style="white">Archie Watson</span></a></td>
            </tr>
```

I am a complete novice at this so any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

1

2.
                Attain 
                  (7)

mid-division, headway well over 1f out, soon chasing leaders, led inside final furlong, ran on

5/2 Fav
9 10-12 
67
Mr S WalkerArchie Watson
2
5

6.
                Muthraab Aldaar 
              (IRE)

```
              (4)
```

tracked leader, led over 1f out, soon hung left, headed inside final furlong, not run on

11/1
5 9-11  p
59
Miss S Stevens (7)J R Boyle
3
½

1.
                Black Caesar 
              (IRE)

```
              (5)
```

led until over 1f out, soon rallied, weakened closing stages

3/1 2Fav
7 10-7 
69
Miss M E Spencer (7)P Hide
4
1½

7.
                Edge 
              (IRE)

```
              (1)
```

held up towards rear, headway over 1f out, chased leaders inside final furlong, never able to challenge

6/1
7 10-2  b
57
Mr R BirkettB J Llewellyn
5
1

Comment: the class attribute should be one of "starting-price", "age-weight" etc., i think

Comment: Thanks asifzuba. I can now get those different class attributes. I'm wondering if you can help with one more query. I'm also trying to get sectional times from the same site, but when I try different scraps I'm getting zero again. i have tried several tags and class attributes so not sure what's going on.

Comment: This is one of the scrapes I've tried - results = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class':'sectionals-time'})   What I don't understand about this is when I right click on the a sectional time on the website and click inspect it then highlights "sectionals-time" so not sure why it's returning zero results.

Comment: This is the highlighted HTML it shows:                                                             
      <span class="sectionals-time" data-tooltip="Running Total: 14.9">14.9</span>

Comment: It would help if you gave the URL you are using, we could then se all of the HTML and also [edit] the question to include what your expected CSV file should look like.

Comment: Hey Martin, thanks. So the URL is: http://www.attheraces.com/racecard/Lingfield/2-June-2018/1740

Comment: As I added previously in my questions, the results have different tabs, the Full Results tab I can now pull the data  need, but the "sectional times" and "sectional tools" tabs are proving difficult. Thanks in advance.